# rgl Problems: surface3d problem when plotting squares

Tags: r, rgl

I want to visualize a square with rgl have problems with my code. First 4 `surface3d` code chunks are working, but the last two aren't.
It is exactly the same type of code and I don´t understand the reason why `rgl` cannot plot it.

See my code below:

```
open3d()

A<-c(0,1)
B<-c(0,2)
C<-c(0,1)

x_3D<-c(min(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)

x_3D<-c(min(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)

x_3D<-c(min(A),min(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)

x_3D<-c(max(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)

##last surfaces are not ploted but also no error

x_3D<-c(min(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),min(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)

x_3D<-c(min(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(max(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
surface3d(x=x_3D, y=y_3D, z=z_3D)
```

Can someone see my mistake?

EDIT: edited the c&p mistake, but still not rendering the last two surfaces.

Comment: C&P mistake is corrected, but still not working. The last two squares are is systematically the same code as for the x_3D constant which is working fine so I don´t understand the problem. Corners would be (0, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1) so no thin line but a square- or am I wrong?

Comment: If I am wrong about the points, why is the x_3D constant working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the `surface3d()` function works.  When `x` and `y` are vectors (as in your data), it attaches the `x` values to each row of the `z` matrix, and the `y` values to each column.

In your third example, where `x_3D` is constant, this is fine, because you have two different `z_3D` values for each `y_3D` value.  But in the last two examples, each `x_3D` value gets the same `z_3D` value, so the "surface" is degenerate.

You can see this by adding row and column names to the `z_3D` matrix.  For example, with the last one:

```r
A<-c(0,1)
B<-c(0,2)
C<-c(0,1)

x_3D<-c(min(A),max(A))
y_3D<-c(max(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)

rownames(z_3D) <- paste("x=", x_3D)
colnames(z_3D) <- paste("y=", y_3D)
z_3D
#>      y= 2 y= 2
#> x= 0    0    0
#> x= 1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This will plot a single cell on the surface, with each of the vertices `(0, 2, 0)` and `(1, 2, 1)` repeated twice.  That is infinitely thin, so it is invisible.

On the other hand, the same calculation with your third example gives

```r
A<-c(0,1)
B<-c(0,2)
C<-c(0,1)

x_3D<-c(min(A),min(A))
y_3D<-c(min(B),max(B))
z_3D<-matrix(c(min(C),max(C)),nrow = 2,ncol = 2)

rownames(z_3D) <- paste("x=", x_3D)
colnames(z_3D) <- paste("y=", y_3D)
z_3D
#>      y= 0 y= 2
#> x= 0    0    0
#> x= 0    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The cell now has 4 different points:  `(0, 0, 0)`, `(0, 2, 0)`, `(0, 0, 1)` and `(0, 2, 1)`, so it is not degenerate, and you can see it.

By the way, it would probably make more sense to use `quads3d` to print single quadrilaterals rather than using `surface3d`; then this would have been obvious.  And if you just want a rectangular prism, transforming `cube3d()` is a quick way to get it.